# Android Sdk Error in Installing Macos React Native

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I have completed almost all the steps for reac native installation. but i am getting android sdk error. I made the android studio settings. i still get error.

I made the android studio settings. the simulator is installed and I have installed the necessary tools, but I still get an error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPIWF.jpg)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add the error message as text and not an image, and check out [ask] when you can. Look in your build.gradle for the version of the Android SDK you need. Have you installed that one from Android Studio?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.